# Cannot access subdirectory of private file system

Tags: 6, files

Why can I download a file from site.com/system/files/ but not site.com/system/files/protected/? Ownership is the same, permissions are 777, but I get a page not found. This is confusing to me.

Comment: Perhaps this is of any use? http://drupal.org/node/1071944

Comment: do you checked drupal file system setting in `admin/settings/file-system` ?